# Altova XMLspy 2014: Multi-line xpath in XSD 1.1 assertions

Tags: xpath, xsd, assertions, altova, xmlspy

In Altova XMLspy 2014, in a XSD 1.1 document, if I add an assertion, I can insert a XPATH 2.0 expresion for the "test" atribute of the assertion, but only ONE line is shown. **How can I enter a multi-line xpath in an assertion?**

Of course, I can enter a multi-line xpath in text view. But I'm using a graphical tool to edit my XSD files easily, so I would like to edit complex xpath expressions graphically (in schema view).

In other components (for example, in annotations) I can press control+intro to insert multiple lines. I can't do it in assertions.

Even worse, if I enter a multi-line xpath assertion in text view, and I change to schema view ("Schema Overview" or "Content Model View") and try to edit the xpath, then the multi-line xpath is shown as only one line.

Multi-line xpath in assertions is required for advanced (complex) node checking. For example, the following xpath:

```
every $symbol in symbols/symbol satisfies
    every $state in states/state satisfies
        some $tran in transition-function/transition satisfies
            $tran/@current-symbol eq $symbol 
            and $tran/@current-state eq $state
```

can be easily understood only with a multi-line format.

Xpath 2.0 is near to be a programming languaje, very useful to check relations between node values. So, as a programming languaje, the expresions can be long and complex, and the multi-line feature is absolutely required.

Perhaps am I missing some setup option to enable it?